# JSF 2.0 partial rendering on page on document load

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a page, one section of which I want to load only after the whole page is loaded. For this, I'm using the following code on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("In the JS");
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $.post(jspPath+'/myCommunity/ajax/hotTopicDiscussion.faces', 
                function(data) {
                    jsf.ajax.request(this, 'post', {render: 'discussionTopic'});
                }
            );  
        }
    );
</script>
```

also

```
<h:panelGroup id="discussionTopic" reRendered="#{discussionBean.doRender}">
```

This `doRender` is a bean property which I set once the AJAX call is done. But this is not loading the data. I can see the ajax method is getting called.

Comment: Why do send post request to `jspPath+'/myCommunity/ajax/hotTopicDiscussion.faces'` before you do actual jsf ajax request?

Comment: What is `rerendered` attribute in `h:panelGroup`? Does it actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that your call of `jsf.ajax.request` is incorrect. According to [JsDoc reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.request) arguments of `request` are following:

> source:
>       The DOM element that triggered this Ajax request, or an id string of the element to use as the triggering element.
>
> event:
>       The DOM event that triggered this Ajax request. The event argument is optional.
>
> options:
>       The set of available options that can be sent as request parameters to control client and/or server side request processing.

So first element must be some element inside form or may be form itself. You may try to pass form's id or form element itself to this function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *really* need to submit a form ajaxically? That's where the `jsf.ajax.request()` is for. It seems like that you just want to load some static content inside some `<div>`. Just do as follows

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("#{request.contextPath}/myCommunity/ajax/hotTopicDiscussion.faces", function(data) {
            $("#discussionTopic").html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
<h:panelGroup id="discussionTopic" layout="block" />
```

Or, simpler, with [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#discussionTopic").load("#{request.contextPath}/myCommunity/ajax/hotTopicDiscussion.faces");
    });
</script>
<h:panelGroup id="discussionTopic" layout="block" />
```

In both cases, I assume that the `hotTopicDiscussion.xhtml` has `<ui:composition>` as root element and that it contains only the necessary HTML (and thus not `<html>` and so on).

If you indeed *really* need to submit a form ajaxically, then simplest would be to let JS "click" the button programmatically. It will delegate all the way up to the proper and needed `jsf.ajax.request()` call. A `jsf.ajax.request()` call is useless anyway without a physical form/button component on the page. You can if necessary hide the form by CSS.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[id='form:button']")[0].onclick();
    });
</script>
<h:form id="form" style="display:none;">
    <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <f:ajax render=":discussionTopic" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="discussionTopic" layout="block" />
```

Comment: Hi,hotTopicDiscussion.xhtml has only the

Comment: hotTopicDiscussion.xhtml has ajax call something like : <f:view locale="#{aqLocaleBean.locale}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{discussionBean.renderDiscussionPanel}" />
</f:view> . This is getting called by someother page on the pageload and the render part is on tthis page only