# jsf.ajax.request not work on Firefox

Tags: ajax, jsf, firefox

I have an application based on JSF 2.1 and Primefaces.
I need to make an ajax request using Jquery and update the page status.
Here the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:view>
        <h:head>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h:outputText id="counterViewer" value="#{dataController.outputMessage}"
                          styleClass="counter-viewer" />
            <h:form id="dataForm" >
                <h:outputScript>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery(document).on("count", function(event, count) {
                            alert( "Count: " + count );
                            document.getElementById("#{view.getClientId(facesContext)}:counterViewer").innerText = count;   
                            var hiddenCountValue = document.getElementById("#{view.getClientId(facesContext)}:dataForm:hiddenCountValue");
                            hiddenCountValue.value = count;
                            jsf.ajax.request(hiddenCountValue, 'change');
                        });
                     });
                </h:outputScript>
                <h:inputHidden id="hiddenCountValue" value="#{dataController.outputMessage}"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

When I use Chrome everything works fine but on firefox 22 the jsf.ajax.request(hiddenCountValue, 'change'); function doesn't work.

Are there other functions that I can use to run my code also on Firefox?
Why doesn't jsf.ajax.request(hiddenCountValue, 'change'); work on firefox?

Thanks

Lucaf:view>

When I use Chrome everithyngs work fine but on firefox the

> jsf.ajax.request(hiddenCountValue, 'change');

function seems not work.

Are there other functions that I can use to make my code more compatible?
Why

> jsf.ajax.request(hiddenCountValue, 'change');

not work on firefox?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

It should also not have worked in Chrome at all. It's likely caused by a misinterpretation. Perhaps the request is actually sent, but even then, it wouldn't do anything useful in the server side. You namely don't have any `<f:ajax>` on the `<h:inputHidden>` which would decode the `jsf.ajax.request()`.

Throw away this clumsy hack/workaround attempt. As you're already using PrimeFaces, just grab its `<p:remoteCommand>` ([showcase example here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf)).

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="sendCount" process="@this" action="#{bean.processCount}" />
</h:form>
<h:outputScript target="body">
    $(document).on("count", function(event, count) {
        $(".counter-viewer").text(count);
        sendCount([{ name: "count", value: count }]);
     });
</h:outputScript>
```

with

```
public void processCount() {
    String count = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestParameterMap().get("count");
    // ...
}
```

To learn how `jsf.ajax.request` really works, head to the following related questions & answers:

- [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript/)
- [JSF 2.0 partial rendering on page on document load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859106/jsf-2-0-partial-rendering-on-page-on-document-load/)
- [How to use jsf.ajax.request to manually send ajax request in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550165/how-to-use-jsf-ajax-request-to-send-ajax-request-to-a-specified-method-on-table/)
- [How to pass mouse coordinates to backing bean when clicking on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160116/how-to-pass-mouse-coordinates-to-backing-bean-when-clicking-on-an-image/)